# Is the Destiny's shield the most powerful shield in the Stargate universe?

Tags: stargate, spaceship

Asgard's shields are said to be the best. But isn't the Destiny's shield the most powerful shield in any spaceship? This can be concluded because it was able to survive in a star.

Does this mean that no weapon in the Stargate universe can harm Destiny?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At minimum, the Destiny's shields are not better than Atlantis's shields.

Destiny is the oldest<sup>1</sup> Ancient technology we have ever seen on-screen.  It was launched while they still lived on Earth, before they built the Milky Way's gate system - its gate technology was far more limited, and only able to reach a couple Stargates in the galaxy at a time.  Likewise, the gate address to Destiny was stored in the database using the Milk Way gate system's glyphs.

In *Stargate: Atlantis*, the Daedalus's Asgard shields were shown many times to vastly more powerful when powered by an Ancient ZPM.  However, it has never managed to stand up to multiple Wraith hive ships for very long.  Atlantis's shields on the other hand, can last an extended amount of time against multiple hive ships.

As far as I know, there has never been a direct comparison that would let us determine how strong Asgard shields are compared to the Destiny.  Atlantis's shields may or may not be stronger than Destiny's shields, but they're definitely not weaker.  However, I would bet that they are stronger due to the huge time span between when Destiny was built and Atlantis was built.

<sup>1</sup> Well, *just about* the oldest.  There are a few scenes in the movie *The Ark of Truth* that are from even further in the past, showing some Ancients escaping the Ori.  In the second one, we see some pages in a notebook that show a Stargate being designed, with its owner saying "I had the most amazing idea last night...".  Some of the technology in the background is reminiscent of Destiny's technology, or what it might have looked like before it had been run down by age.

Comment: That is pretty descriptive answer. I hope someday they will make more stargate series and explain lot of things which is not explainable now

Comment: I gave this a +1, but I do have an objection to the second paragraph. My understanding was that the dialing limit *from* Destiny was due to the seeded gate's low power. Destiny wouldn't let passengers dial someplace they couldn't get back from.

Comment: @T.J.L. Destiny locked out addresses that were too dangerous for some reason, and this was displayed differently enough from in/out of range that they were able to identify it pretty quickly on arriving to the ship.  So while power available definitely has something to do with it (the whole dial-Earth-from-a-star part), Destiny's normal range is limited the same as the seeded gates, and neither Milky Way nor Pegasus gates needed any external power source to reach other gates within the galaxy.

Comment: @Izkata Milky Way and Pegasus gates had DHDs for a power source. Seed gates only had the handheld controller.

Answer (score 6):

In Stargate Atlantis 3.12 the Daedalus shields Atlantis from a giant solar flare (coronal mass ejection) occuring every 15thsd (Atlantian?) years. They need a ZPM for that but the Daedalus withstands that blast for quite some time. So it looks like the Daedalus shields are already quite up to the power than the Destinys shields. As already mentioned the Atlantian shields should be quite more powerful than the Destinys shields.

[image: Daedalus shielding of a coronal mass ejection]

http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Echoes

Theres a SG1 Episode called "Space Race" where an alien vessel named "Sebrus" slinghots around the sun while being in the corona.

[image: Serbrus]

Altough there is the well known SG1 episode where Carter detonates a stargate inside the sun to cause an explosion of the sun to destroy an huge number of Goauld ships.

So it seems the power of shield technology in StarGate varies from race to race.

Answer (score -2):

Destiny was launched millions of years ago. Technology moves slowly but when it moves it moves in leaps, now saying that. The ancients have had millions of years worth of technological advancement since then. So have the asgard and the furlings ( I know we haven't seen them, but I'm putting them on the same level as the two pervously mentioned because they were at one point)

(Back to my point) there would be many ships shields stronger than Destiny. My list goes,

1. Atlantis ( powered by 3 ZPM's)
2. Ancients Aurora class ( with zpm)
3. O neill class ships
4. Ori mother ship.
5. Asgard science vessel ( the daniel jackson )
6. Asgard baliskner class
7. Acients Aurora class ( no zpm)
8. Bc-304 ( not fully upgraded )
9. Ancient cruiser
10. Furling ship. ( honourable mention )
11. Nox city ship. ( no idea of the shields potential)

( another note ) if the SGC was able to utilise all the asgard advancement giving to them. ( may take some years to achieve) and create a new ship, a Bc- 305 it would move up to 3rd on the list.

Comment: Could you [edit] in some evidence for why these are stronger than Destiny’s shields?

Comment: It is also difficult to accept anything regarding the Furlings. While they were among the four races we know three details about them. Their name, what their letters/writing looks like, and that they were one of the four. Just because they were of the four does not mean they had advanced shields. they could have just gotten into the group on a technicality or for bringing tacos to the universe...And as you also point out we can not say the Nox shields are more advanced given we have no confirmation they even actually have them or how good they are

Comment: I don't think the Nox have any shields.  They rely entirely on their cloaking, and as far as we know their floating city isn't a ship like Atlantis.

Comment: They could have shields. We really just don't know... Either way @Jason, I should have said yesterday welcome to the site! I know how hard it is to build your reputation against answered questions... Stick to it and you will get the basic permissions you need to do anything here!

Comment: To cover my ass. I know we know little to nothing of the furlings. But we have seen there tech, and it's very advanced. The last two on my list are nothing more the. Honourable mentions. I just can't see them not being hugely advanced.